# Review your selections and rate them in Webform within Drupal 7

Tags: webforms

I have created a Form with the help of amazing Webform module in Drupal 7. It's a kind of various selections (through checkboxes) user makes.

This is all working fine but the problem is the last step.

I want user to review all the selections he made in the last page and give a priority to each selected option.

Now there are two things I want to do:-

- Review the selections made in the Form at the end.
- Prioritize them; by selecting a number 1-5 with each entry.

Please pardon my ignorance, but is it even possible with Webform?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Preview functionality is now part of the 7.x-4.x branch. There is an involved discussion about it here: [Summary/review/preview page before final submission in multistep forms](https://www.drupal.org/node/435232).

As for prioritizing, I think you would want to add a rating field for each field, and theme the form and the preview such that the initial form would not show the rating field, and the preview would.

Depending on what you want to do with those ratings, you may want to use a module like [Star Rating](https://www.drupal.org/project/starrating) (which is a simple module that doesn't have any other dependencies) or [FiveStar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) (which is more complex and has more functionality).

Comment: You guys! You are amazing bunch of beautiful people!!!

Comment: The 7.x-4.x branch breaks my Webform. It somehow isn't working with my Drupal. Any idea why? :(

Answer (score 1):

for your first issue:

you should check out node/[nid]/webform/configure - At the bottom of the page you find "Preview page" if you activate it, the user can see a preview button.

for your second issue:

as far as i know there is no module that does that. So i think you have to code it by yourself!
As a startingpoint i would say you have to use the hook_form_alter() hook and insert your priorization fields... after that you have to alter the submit handler for saving the priority values.

*edit

after some research i found the [webform-fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform-fivestar) module... but i'm not sure if it is possible to show them only on the preview page and make them editable... i think you need some custom-code...

is it really necessary to rate them on the review page and not directly on the form?

Comment: You guys! You are amazing bunch of beautiful people!!!

Comment: For your question, we need the checkbox selections to be prioritized from 1-5. Since it's a workshop selection, we take top 5 workshops that user selects and then ask him to prioritize those selections. This would ensure that when we arrange the workshops we try our best to get the first priority, if not then second and so forth. Hope I am clear.